# Import Weights from Keras Classifier into TF Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a classifier that I trained using keras that is working really well. It uses `keras.applications.MobileNetV2`.

This classifier is well trained on around 200 categories, and has a high accuracy.

However, I would like to use the feature extraction layers from this classifier as part of an object detection model.

I have been using the Tensorflow Object Detection API, and looking into the SSDLite+MobileNetV2 model. I can start to run training, but the training is very slow and the bulk of the loss comes from the classification stage.

What I would like to do is assign the weights from my keras `.h5` model to the Feature Extraction layer of MobileNetV2 in Tensorflow, but I'm not sure of the best way to do that.

I can load the `h5` file easily, and get a list of layer names:

```
import keras

keras_model = keras.models.load_model("my_classifier.h5")

keras_names = [l.name for l in keras_model.layers]

print(keras_names)
```

I can also restore the tensorflow checkpoint from the object detection API and export the layers with weights:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('models/model.ckpt.meta')

    what = new_saver.restore(sess, 'models/model.ckpt')


    tf_names = []
    for op in sess.graph.get_operations():
        if "MobilenetV2" in op.name and "Assign" in op.name:
            tf_names.append(op.name)

    print(tf_names)
```

I cannot seem to get a good match-up between layer names from keras and from tensorflow. Even if I could I'm not sure of the next steps.

If anyone could give me some advice about the best way to approach this I would be very grateful.

Update:

I followed Sharky's suggestion below, with a slight modification:

```
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(os.path.join(keras_checkpoint_dir, 'keras_model.ckpt.meta'))

new_saver.restore(sess, os.path.join(keras_checkpoint_dir, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(keras_checkpoint_dir)))
```

However unfortunately I now get this error:

> NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Restoring from checkpoint
>   failed. This is most likely due to a Variable name or other graph key
>   that is missing from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not
>   altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:
>
> Key
>   FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_6/project/BatchNorm/gamma
>   not found in checkpoint    [[node save/RestoreV2_295 (defined at
>   :7)  = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0,
>   save/RestoreV2_295/tensor_names,
>   save/RestoreV2_295/shape_and_slices)]]     [[{{node
>   save/RestoreV2_196/_393}} = _Recvclient_terminated=false,
>   recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_789_save/RestoreV2_196",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]

Any ideas on how to get rid of this error?

Comment: I guess the easiest way is to convert keras model to estimator, save ckpt file and use it. Will this suit your case?

Comment: I can give it a shot, I just found this reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/estimator/model_to_estimator. Looks like it's worth a try

Comment: You can inspect checkpoint file with `tf.train.list_variables`, and compare it with global_variables collection. You can also load only specific variables with tf.train_init_from_checkpoint`. Or maybe it's just a name/scope mismatch

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator`

```py
estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model, model_dir=path)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, os.path.join(path/keras, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(path/keras)))
    print(tf.global_variables())
```

This should do the job. Note that it will create a subdirectory inside originally specified path.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I ran into another issue